# Make [kvl] and [kcl] a synonym of [kirchhoffs-laws] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently noticed some questions were tagged [kvl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kvl) ([#1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/588937/revisions), [#2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/589416/revisions)), so I retagged them using the correct [kirchhoffs-laws](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirchhoffs-laws). There are currently 25 questions tagged [kvl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kvl), and "KVL" is a common acronym so it seems appropriate to make the acronym tag a synonym of the tag that has the full name, a wiki, etc. There are currently no questions tagged [kcl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kcl) but it might be a good idea to make that a synonym as well. Would a moderator kindly merge the tags and make the synonym(s)?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think these abbreviations are that common or helpful, so in this specific case it might be better to just drop the confusing abbreviations entirely and replace them with either [kirchoffs-laws](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirchoffs-laws) or make a new tag called [kirchoffs-voltage-law](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirchoffs-voltage-law).

---

Generally speaking, any user with sufficient rep can propose that tags are to be made synonymous, though the feature is well-hidden.

- Click on the tag such as [kirchoffs-laws](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirchoffs-laws) which takes you here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirchhoffs-laws.
- Click on "Learn More" which opens up the ["tag wiki"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/kirchhoffs-laws/info) (which is awful in this specific case and could do with some improvements).
- On the right side, scroll down to the bottom where you find the link [suggest tag synonym »](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/kirchhoffs-laws/synonyms).
- If I remember correctly, users with sufficient participation in the [kirchoffs-laws](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirchoffs-laws) tag can now vote if they agree or disagree. It's good to create a meta post whenever you do a synonym request in order to draw attention to it.

This is a low traffic tag though, so I'm not sure how well this will end up. We might need mod help in the end after all...

Comment: I'm well aware of the process to propose a tag wiki, but it is almost impossible to get it approved because it is so "well-hidden". It is much easier to just ask a moderator to do it, which is what I'm doing (and it has worked successfully here in the past).

Comment: I don't think the abbreviations are helpful, either, which is why I'm asking to make them synonyms so that users (like me) don't have to manually replace them with the appropriate kirchhoffs-laws tag. They are not especially common but with at least 25 instances of the "kvl" tag (plus however many instances in which "kvl" has already been removed) it is common enough to be a problem.